# No Space Validator in Angular

Tags: regex, angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms, angular-validation

I'm hanlding more than 10 forms in my project with many input fields. The problem is my fields taking empty spaces as values. As for now what I did is getting the value of the field on change and trim it and check the length with 0. If yes throw 'don't use empty spaces' , else take the value.

```
<input (change)='check($event)'>

check(data){
   if(data.trim() === 0 ){
       console.log('contains empty spaces'   
   }else{
        console.log('contains data') 
   }
}
```

But as the field or form increases this will be a headache. So I'm trying to make this as common module. So that I'll use this as common like service.

note: the validation should happen on pretext (i.e) ' HelloWorld' should throw error but 'Hello World' should not.
Can anyone give me some idea or suggestion to solve this issue..

Thanks in advance

Comment: what formbuilder approach are you following? if your are using reactiveForms approach you can pass validators to you form fields

Comment: If you want to prevent spaces all together:

 isSpace($event) {
    let charCode = ($event.which) ? $event.which : $event.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 32)
      return false;

    return true;
  }

and then on input (keypress)="isSpace($event)"


if you want to preserve spaces, I think maybe add a custom validator that checks spaces etc via regex.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case to create a custom validator. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Answer (score 10, accepted):

trim.validator.ts

```
export const trimValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormControl) => {
  if (control.value.startsWith(' ')) {
    return {
      'trimError': { value: 'control has leading whitespace' }
    };
  }
  if (control.value.endsWith(' ')) {
    return {
      'trimError': { value: 'control has trailing whitespace' }
    };
  }
  return null;
};
```

In any component that wants to use the trim.validator.ts

```
import { trimValidator } from 'path/to/trim.validator'.ts

ctrl: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
  this.ctrl = new FormControl('', trimValidator);
)
```

If you are using template driven forms, you need to create a validation directive. Just follow the steps from the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms)

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/trailing-whitespace-validator)

Comment: Thanks tomasz, but can u help me in having this in a seperate module. so that it'll be available as common for all components

Comment: Its a regular function. You can put it in a file `trim.validator.ts`, export it, and then import it in any components that want to use it. Just like you do with build in validators. It does not need to be a part of any `@NgModule`.

Comment: @TheLawliet94 Glad I could help :) Can you mark my answer as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using includes like this

```
data.includes(" ")
```

It will return true if the string contains spaces.